# Problema com URL no AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Estou com um sistema rodando localmente, feito em Spring boot Java no back-end e Angular no front-end. Mas tenho um problema ocorrendo no front-end que é o seguinte:

Quando levanto minha aplicação e acesso o `localhost/clinica/` sou redirecionado para meu index que carrega minha `home.html`; até aí tudo bem. A página é carregada certinha com os menus e as informações. 
A url se apresenta assim: `http://localhost/ultravitae/#!/`

No menu tenho uma opção Perfil; quando clico deveria listar os perfis mas não aparece nada. Fica na mesma página anterior. Contudo a url muda, ficando assim: `http://localhost/ultravitae/#!/#%2Fperfil`

Pelo que pude observar, é como se estivesse concatenando a url. Alguém já passou por isso e sabe como resolver?

Meu `index.js` está assim:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('clinica',['ngRoute'])
.config(function($routeProvider){

    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'src/home/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl'
    })
    .when('/perfil', {
        templateUrl: 'src/perfil/perfil.html',
        controller: 'PerfilCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
});
```

O meu home.js assim:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('clinica')
  .controller('HomeCtrl', function() {
  });
```

E o meu perfil.js assim:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('clinica')
.controller('PerfilCtrl', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.perfils = [];

    $http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/private/perfil').then(function(response){
            $scope.perfils = response.data;
        });
});
```

No meu `index.html` tenho uma `div` que deveria apresentar o conteúdo

```
<div id="main">
    <ng-view />
</div>
```

A estrutura de pastas está assim:
ultravitae `(arquivos: index.html e index.js)`

```
|-> src
|-> home (arquivos: home.html e home.js)
|-> perfil (arquivos: perfil.html e perfil.js)
```

Obs: Fiz o seguinte teste. No `index.js` coloquei para meu index chamar o `perfil.html` ao invés da `home.html` e listou os perfis certinho:
    angular.module('clinica',['ngRoute'])
    .config(function($routeProvider){

```
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'src/perfil/perfil.html',
        controller: 'PerfilCtrl'
    })
    .when('/perfil', {
        templateUrl: 'src/home/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl'

    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Sei que o tópico já é antigo, mas é bom sempre ajudar o próximo.

Enfim, você pode usar no seu href= "#!/perfil" não use  href= "#/perfil", porque ele irá pegar da tabela ASCII %2 que é o espaço.

E deixa seu .config do jeito que tá mesmo! só mude seu link no HTML.

.when('/perfil', {
        templateUrl: 'src/home/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl'`

Answer (score 0):

Já tentou o `$urlRouteProvider`? me parece que ele executa uma chamada diferente, basicamente assistida, enquanto `$routeProvider` roda tudo internamente, segue um exemplo que deu certo para mim em um projeto passado...

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home') //Página principal

  $stateProvider

  .state('home', {

    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: 'templates/home/home.html'

  })

  .state('detalhes', {

    url: '/detalhes/:resId',
    templateUrl: 'templates/conteudo/detalhes.html',
    controller: 'detalhesCtrl'

  })

})
```

Comment: Obriga pela dica Felipe, mas Não funcionou. 

Só uma página que carrega quando subo  a aplicação que é a home,  as demais não carregam de maneira nenhuma.

Answer (score 0):

Tem que colocar a tag base href="/" na index ou home.html e colocar o parâmetro $locationProvider dentro da função config na rota e chamar o parâmetro assim:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

com isso o # não será mais mostrado.